# Mismatch between KS test and qq plot?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, qq-plot

I read many posts about the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, Q-Q plots and CDFs. I decided to ask my own question about some difficulties I have with some real data.

The data I'm using is available on this [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JEyl0wH8dKmLRNSJ9UIRe9z1bCV9mMIf1cRnQ8_qdeM/edit?usp=sharing).

I don't understand the results I get after applying a Q-Q plot and a KS test using a Generalized hyperbolic distribution as reference.

The code I'm using is:

```
library(MASS)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(ghyp)
################################

ghyp.fit <- fit.ghypuv(data, symmetric = FALSE)                 #Fit
Theta <- coef(ghyp.fit)
Theta2 <- coef(ghyp.fit, type = "alpha.delta")
Theta3 <- ghyp(lambda = -1.849622, alpha.bar = 1.822762,         #Parameters of Theta
          mu = 36.12087, sigma = 109.5392, gamma = -9.057124)

##Kolmogorov-Smirnov test - ref: generalized hyperbolic distribution
ks.test(data, "pghyp", Theta3)   

##QQplot
qqghyp(ghyp.fit, gaussian = FALSE, ghyp.col = "black")
```

The $p$-value of the test is $0.09958$ (high enough I guess), but the Q-Q plot doesn't match this result because of the differences in the tails of the distribution.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I not interpreting of these results correctly?

Any help, guide, etc. would be fully appreciated!

Comment: Your plot is not relevant to the KS test because it uses the percents corresponding to the quantiles.  Could you redraw it as such and show that to us?

Comment: What's right and wrong here? The fit is good in the middle and not so good in the tails. This often happens. I have to give a view that K-S is overrated in this role, as it is necessarily more sensitive to deviations in the middle of the distribution, which is often the reverse of what you want. The main deal is what you decide and it's easier to reject the idea of one distribution if you know another that works better.

Comment: You're calculating the p-value of the test statistic as if the distribution parameters were pre-specified rather than estimated from the data.

Comment: I tried some distributions before getting on the generalized hyperbolic, and none of them fited well in the qq plot, most of them were awful. Should I try searching one thats fits better or these is "good enough"? @NickCox

Comment: @Scortchi, The parameters on Theta3 are the same that I got on Theta, so they are estimated from the data.

Comment: That's exactly the point made by @Scortchi: the reported p-value is invalid.  It's grossly inflated because you have fit the distribution to the data, whereas it was computed as if the parameters (*and* the distribution shape itself) had been specified independently of the data.  "Good enough" depends on how you intend to use the fitted distribution.  For many purposes it won't even matter but for other purposes the fit might be considered terrible.

Comment: @whuber, so what is the correct way of doing this? sorry for bothering too much

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't explained what you're really trying to accomplish: all you have done so far is exhibit a failed distribution-fitting procedure!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm trying to estimate a distribution who fits my data, but most of those I tried, don't fit well in the QQ plot. @whuber

Comment: Right--that much is evident.  But what is the purpose of this exercise?  It is unusual to fit some mathematical distribution to data for its own sake.  Often the whole procedure is unnecessary.  (A good indicator of that is when you search widely among many distributional shapes: that shows the choice of distribution isn't expected to reveal anything and you're trying only to find a convenient mathematical approximation.)  When such a fit is needed, it usually is for characterizing some particular feature of the data, such as its behavior in one or both tails.

Comment: @whuber, I need the estimated density distributions of some forecasting errors like wind energy, solar, etc. and then apply a statistical convolution between them to get a "representative" density distribution of a system.

Comment: The code isn't working for me. Has it changed because of the new versions of R?